# Printing Index number of array

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, output, element

I am trying to print an output that would find the max number and also print the index number of the array as well. I am able to print the max number but I am unable to print the index number.

```
public static int findMax(int[] allNumbers) {
    int maxValue = allNumbers[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < allNumbers.length; i++) {
        if (allNumbers[i] > maxValue) {
            maxValue = allNumbers[i];
        }
    }
    return (int) maxValue;
}
```

my array:

`int[] allNumbers = new int[inpNum];`

I can call the max number with the following
    `findMax(number)`

Comment: You don't need to cast maxValue to an int in your return statement. Don't be afraid, it's always an int ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return an array of the max value and index:

```
public static int[] findMax(int[] allNumbers) {
        int maxValue = allNumbers[0];
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < allNumbers.length; i++) {
            if (allNumbers[i] > maxValue) {
                maxValue = allNumbers[i];
                index = i;
            }
        }
        return new int[] {maxValue , index};
}
```

Comment: when I try this code i am receiving I@55f96302 when my output is printed

Comment: @SPJava use the `Arrays.toString` method. `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(findMax(yourArray)));`

Comment: Thank you! that worked now my only question is if I want to add wording so instead of the output showing: 100, 1 I would want it to be 100 on position 1. Anyway of doing this?

Comment: @SPJava store a reference to the returned array and then index into the array to get the corresponding elements, providing your wording... --> `int[] result =  findMax(yourArray);
        System.out.println(result[0] + " on position " + result[1]);`

Comment: question what happens if two numbers are the same how can I print the index number twice? example input numbers 100, 100, 10 should print 100 on position 1 and 2